# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.4

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Android Studio Version (3.6.1) I'm trying to compile an old project I think I did in Eclipse on another computer. BTW I imported the project into Android Studio Version (3.6.1)

I have 5.6.4 installed!

C:\Users\Michael>gradle -v

Welcome to Gradle 5.6.4!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Incremental Groovy compilation
 - Groovy compile avoidance
 - Test fixtures for Java projects
 - Manage plugin versions via settings script

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/release-notes.html

---

### Gradle 5.6.4

Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 25.60-b23)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

C:\Users\Michael>

***Could not post the whole log because of the following:
You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links.***

Here's the log:

11:32 AM    Gradle sync started

11:33 AM    Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.4.
                    Searched in the following locations:
                    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.6.4/gradle-5.6.4.pom
                    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.6.4/gradle-5.6.4.jar
                    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.6.4/gradle-5.6.4.pom
                    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.6.4             Required by:
                    project :
                    Consult IDE log for more details (Help... (show balloon)

Answer (score 1):

You have mistaken "**gradle-wrapper.properties**" with "**build.gradle**" file.

The Gradle Tools highest version by the time I'm writing this comment is 3.6.1 . You need to mention Gradle version as **5.6.4** in "**{YourProjectDir}/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**".

Please comment if you cannot resolve.

BTW, Use Android Studio welcome wizard to import a project from Eclipse to Android Studio. Check the below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: #Mon Mar 09 20:02:31 PDT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Comment: Are still facing the issue? 

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Comment: Thank you a lot for explanation. You saved my day.